# Read line from file, manipulate, and then append to another file

Tags: shell-script, sed

To pool specific content from a batch of files, I do

```
for ID in {92..128}; do 
    sed '3q;d' directory_$ID/stats
done
```

Now what if want to put the `$ID` in front of each line read (preferably shifting the  columns in a fixed-width manner) and then append the line to a report.txt file (creating it if it doesn't exist). I did some research on this but there seem to be many potential ways of doing it, none of which I'm familiar with as a new Linux user (perhaps I should just use Python next time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append `$ID` (with space) at the beginning of each line something like

```
sed "s/^/$ID /"
```

should work (notice double, not single quotes). If you want to do this within the given loop and redirect output to `report.txt` try

```
for ID in {92..128}; do 
    sed "s/^/$ID /;3q;d" directory_$ID/stats
done > report.txt
```

Comment: Ha, that looks rather like a Vim command. Now if there were an easy way for me to maintain fixed-width spacing (e.g. put 4 spaces after a 2-digit ID and 3 spaces after a 3-digit one), that would be excellent.

Comment: How about using tabs instead of spaces: `sed "s/^/$ID\t/"`? This way columns will be aligned properly.